# Build Settings and Deploy Target for worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am running in WLPlatform version 7.1.0, for some reason after upgrading from 7.0 to 7.1  I am noticing strange problem where build setting and deploy target for remote WL server is not working correctly. 
That is change in wlclient.properties file still reflect older values for server how ever port and server context is updated correctly.

```
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = {still shows my local server name}
wlServerPort = 9080
wlServerContext = /xxx/
```

Any idea what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known defect in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, schedule to be fixed soon: *PI48848 INCORRECT SERVER HOST IS WRITTEN IN WORKLIGHT.PLIST/WLCLIENT.PROPERTIES, IF SERVERHOST IS DIFFERENT THAN LOCALHOST.*

You can open a PMR (support ticket) and request the fix once it is ready.

Comment: Is it possible to go back to 7.0 ?

Comment: Also how do I open PMR ticket, can you pass me a link ?

Comment: Asn an IBM customer you can find previous releases at the IBM Fix Central website. To open a PMR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639

Comment: do you have link to existing ticket, I am unbale to fund the same using above URL

Comment: There is no PMR for this; there is an internal defect.